# Customize query string generated by RESTAdapter/Store

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

When I make a `.find` call on the store as such:

```
this.store.find('user', { age: 24 });
```

It generates the request:

```
GET /user?age=24
```

I cannot figure out how to customize the query parameters that are generated from that request.  I looked through the source for the RESTSerializer and RESTAdapter, but didn't see anything that would generate that query string.

I would like to have Ember generate something like :

```
GET /user?details=age eq 24
```

Instead of the default:

```
GET /user?age=24
```

Is this possible?

---

**Links to sources:**

DS.Store:  https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.6/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L44

DS.RESTAdapter:  https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.6/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L13

DS.RESTSerializer:  https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.6/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/rest_serializer.js#L15

Comment: Then I guess you have to write your own `RESTAdapter`.

Comment: ... that is my question. What methods do I override?  As I mentioned in my post, I went through the source and didn't see which methods to change.

Comment: Pls link the source in your question.

Comment: I don't have my own code yet because I don't know what to overwrite yet, that is my question.

Comment: I mean from here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js

Comment: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.6/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L1649
the store calls the adapter here with the params

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.6/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L1371
the adapter is from here - the type is "object" I think

Comment: I think you can set your own adapter type by configuring the container, but I am not familiar with ember.

Comment: The data goes here to the queryString: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.6/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L223
So you have to transform the data in the `adapter.findQuery()` before the `ajax()` call, or in the `store` before the `adapter.findQuery()` call. I think it would make more sense to do this in the `adapter`. There are more `find*()` methods in there, so I guess you have to override all of them if you want your custom queryStrings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your request to `this.store.find('user', {details:'age eq 24'});`

You'll also need to override `pathForType` in order to make `user` singular

```
App.UserAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  pathForType: function(type) {
    var camelized = Ember.String.camelize(type);
    return camelized; //Ember.String.pluralize(camelized);
  },
});
```

Comment: Well that's pretty embarrassing... didn't even think of that :D